# Calculating gradients of cusom loss function with Gradient.Tape

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying custom traning of the network using Gradient.Tape method.
This traning is unsupervised.
The details of network and cost function is as following,
My Network is,

```
def CreateNetwork(inplayer, hidlayer, outlayer,seed):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(hidlayer, input_dim=inplayer, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0,stddev=1/np.sqrt(inplayer),seed=seed), bias_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0,stddev=1/np.sqrt(inplayer),seed=seed), activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(outlayer, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0,stddev=1/np.sqrt(hidlayer),seed=seed), bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros(), activation='linear'))
    return model
```

and my custom cost function is defined as,

```
def H_tilda(J,U,nsamples,nsites,configs,out_matrix):
    EigenValue = 0.0
    for k in range(nsamples):
        config = configs[k,:]
        out_n = out_matrix[k,:]
        exp = 0.0
        for i in range(nsamples):
            n = configs[i,:]
            out_nprime = out_matrix[i,:]
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #    Calculation of Hopping Term
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            hop = 0.0
            for j in range(nsites):
                if j == 0:
                    k = [nsites-1,j+1]
                elif j == (nsites - 1):
                    k = [j-1,0]
                else:
                    k = [j-1,j+1]
                if n[k[0]] != 0:
                    annihiliate1 = np.sqrt(n[k[0]])
                    n1 = np.copy(n)
                    n1[k[0]] = n1[k[0]] - 1
                    n1[j] = n1[j] +1
                    if (config == n1).all():
                        delta1 = 1
                    else:
                        delta1 = 0
                else:
                    annihiliate1 = 0
                    n1 = np.zeros(nsites)
                    delta1 = 0
                if n[k[1]] != 0:
                    annihiliate2 = np.sqrt(n[k[1]])
                    n2 = np.copy(n)
                    n2[k[1]] = n2[k[1]] -1
                    n2[j] = n2[j] + 1
                    if (config == n2).all():
                        delta2 = 1
                    else:
                        delta2 = 0
                else:
                    annihiliate2 = 0
                    n2 = np.zeros(nsites)
                    delta2 = 0
                create = np.sqrt(n[j] + 1)
                hop = hop + create*(annihiliate1*delta1 + annihiliate2*delta2)
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #    Calculation of Onsite Term
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (config == n).all():
                ons = np.sum(np.dot(np.square(n),n - 1))
            else:
                ons = 0.0
            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            phi_value = phi(out_nprime.numpy())
            exp = exp + ((hop + ons) * phi_value)
        Phi_value = phi(out_n.numpy())
        EigenValue = EigenValue + exp/Phi_value
    return np.real(EigenValue/nsamples)
```

I want to do custom traning using GradientTape method, for which I used following lines ,

```
optimizer = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
    tape.watch(tf.convert_to_tensor(configs))
    out_matrix = model(configs)
    print(out_matrix)
    eival = H_tilda(J,U,nsamples,nsites,configs,out_matrix)
    print(eival)
gradients = tape.gradient(tf.convert_to_tensor(eival), model.trainable_weights)
print(gradients)
```

But the gradient I am getting is NONE,

```
output: [None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Yes, of course it returns None, your loss is implemented in numpy, it should be implemented with tensorflow functions, and also I don't think your loss is differentiable. You cannot use any function as loss. It needs to be carefully selected.

Comment: thanks, Dr. Snoopy, but I have a problem using tensors in the cost function as I have loops inside the cost function, and using tensors inside the loop is difficult can you please suggest how I can use tensors inside the loop. and also can you provide references of some examplese where tensors are used inside loop.

Comment: See [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)